# Stellaris servo control with gamepad

Tags: microcontroller, texas-instruments, gamepad, motordriver

I'm looking for a solution to control 3 or more servo's with a gamepad connected to my laptop and the MCU I'd like to use is the Stellaris launchpad or MSP430 by Texas instruments. I've searched almost everywhere it seems and still have not found the answer, the project is a pc controlled telescope mount.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: What exactly is your question?  And if the question is "how do I do this" that is too broad for our site.  If you have a specific question e.g. "I can't get my protocol between the micro and the laptop working, here are some code details..." or "My pwm control for the servos isn't doing what I expect, here are some code details..." we can help with that.

Comment: I see, and I should have been more specific. What I wanted was a source for code to implement, yet the only code I have is to drive 3 servo's with keyboard presses. http://e2e.ti.com/group/microcontrollerprojects/m/stellarismicrocontrollerprojects/664800.aspx
Is there away to add more lines for more servo control (2 more servo's) and also A way to make them a little more sensitive or atleast "smooth".
The last thing I'd like to know is how to implement code for the arduino onto the stellaris with http://energia.nu/ if anyone know's a good resource for learning?

Answer (score 0):

Did not tried it myself, but this should work.

You need to install driver for your gamepad. I use this: http://www.motioninjoy.com/download

And then you can use something like "Object Oriented Input System" (google for it, its easy to find).

For communicating with launchpad - most obvious to use a virtual serial port, that is built in it.
For communicate with serial port from your programm - you can use boost::asio lib.
Here is excellent example of how to use it with serial ports:
http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html

Sooo, thats all you need.
All those libraries written for c/c++. Its the only language I know, so I'm sure you can find another, simplier ways. For example - I heard, that python have some awesome serial port support - much simplier than boost::asio.

Good luck with your project! I tried to to something alike, but lost my enthusiasm.

Comment: Oops, didnt read commentaries. But i hope my post still can be usefull.